# How to define a string with values from a defined list in SCHEME

Tags: scheme

Please help me to do define a string like this..

I have a list which has the values 
(define temp-list (list '398 '150 '1.15 '2875 '-900 '1565 '800 '230 '200 '0 '0 '0))

I Should declare this as..
(define b "398 150 1.15 2875 -900 1565 800 230 200 0 0 0")

How can i do this in scheme?

Comment: Looks like homework... if so, be sure to cite the helpful fellow who provided you with the answer!

Comment: There's no reason to quote numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [SRFI 13](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-13/srfi-13.html) loaded, you can use `string-join` like so:

```
(define b (string-join (map number->string temp-list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://codepad.org/8DH8mCTQ:

```
(define temp-list (list '398 '150 '1.15 '2875 '-900 '1565 '800 '230 '200 '0 '0 '0))

(define b
    (let loop ((xs temp-list) (zs '()))
      (if (null? (cdr xs))
          (apply string-append (reverse (cons (number->string (car xs)) zs)))
          (loop (cdr xs) (cons " " (cons (number->string (car xs)) zs))))))

(write b)
```